# Error when trying to retrieve text using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to retrieve text from a website (indeed.com) but even though I'm using the right ID and Class for some reason I'm unable to retrieve it.

This is how the HTML looks like:

```
<div id="jobDescriptionText" class="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText">
```

The website has different classes and id' at different times so I've tried to account for it by adding different id's and classes' based on the HTML in a try except block. I only run into trouble with getting the text when the above html line pops up. This is a part of the code:

```
 try:
   for i in range(14):
   postings=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result')
 except:
    print('Error in retrieving postings')

 counts=0 
 rate=[]

 for job in postings:

  try:
    result_html = job.get_attribute('innerHTML')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(result_html, 'html.parser')

  except:
    print('Error in retreiving job from postings')

 sleep(randint(10,15))

 while True:

  try: #retreiving text
    try: 
      job.click()
      driver.implicitly_wait(7)
      description0=(driver.find_element_by_id('vjs-content').text)
      counts=counts+1
      break
    except Exception as e:
      job.click()
      driver.implicitly_wait(7)
      description0=(driver.find_element_by_id('vjs-desc').text)
      counts=counts+1
      break
    try:
       job.click()
       driver.implicitly_wait(7)
       description0=(driver.find_element_by_id('jobDescriptionText').text)
       counts=counts+1
       break
    except Exception as e:
        job.click()
        driver.implicitly_wait(7)
        description0=(driver.find_element_by_class('jobsearch-jobDescriptionText').text)
        counts=counts+1
        break
except:
   print("Error in retreiving description for listing")
   break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have shared the right HTML:

```
<div id="jobDescriptionText" class="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText">
```

it does not have any text in it.

so calling `.text` on them does not make any sense. rather have a right locator where you see text in it in HTML DOM.

Comment: @cruisepandey the html is`<div id="jobDescriptionText" class="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText"><p>Experienced and professional waiters.</p></d>`

Comment: First we need to check if id `jobDescriptionText` is unique, if it is then call `.getText()` directly, if that don't work call `.getAttribute('innerText')` on `driver.findElement().getAttribute(innerText)`, print that and you should be good to go.

Comment: Both. With getText() and .getAttribute('innerText')

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result')
```

There is no `result` class name in the HTML

```
<div id="jobDescriptionText" class="jobsearch-jobDescriptionText">
```

If the `result` class is on the parent, you need to select out the child elements of that parent to use in your `for job in postings`, otherwise you will only find one "container" element, that doesn't have the text you expect.